# An incomprehensible problem with the Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $ B = \left \{x \in \mathbb {R} ^ n: | x | <1 \right \} $. For which $ \alpha $ (depending on $ n $) the function $ u (x) = | x | ^ {- \alpha} \sin x $ belongs to the space $ H ^ 1 \left (B \right) $

**My attempt:**

If we assume that the sine is continuous on the closure and consider the radial function. Although, on the other hand, the same result can be achieved simply by saying that the sine modulus is less than 1

By the theorem (using open and bounded B) that u is in the Sobolev space if and only if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} u(x)$ exists

*Question:*

Is the reasoning correct? It turns out that there is no limit, is that so?

Comment: Your attempt is written in a not very understandable form, and it would be better if you write it better. Anyway, I think that this exercise is better to be solved by applying directly the definition of Sobolev space

Comment: What is $\sin(x)$ if x is a vector?